# Launch a .exe when a specific USB device is connected

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, autorun, plug-and-play

I would like to **launch** a .exe **when a specific USB device is connected** (for instance a Akai LPK25 USB MIDI keyboard).

Is there a simple way to do this with Windows?